# Facebook api - Invite only those that don't have the app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this method in order to allow the end user to invite friends:

```
     FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'app message!', data:'tracking information for the user'});
```

The user is prompted with a facebook dialog in which he can choose to invite:

1. All friends
2. my app users (the users that have the app installed/allowed)
3. Friends to Invite (those that don't have the app installed - my goal)

Or in a brief image:

[image]

I don't want the end user to have a choice here, only prompt the third option - those that don't have the app.

Can someone point me to the right direction on this?
I'm using php + facebook's php sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'app message!',filters:'app_non_users' data:'tracking information for the user'});
```

Comment: hey thanks! and just correct it to a JASON: filters: ['app_non_users'],

Comment: Even i was confuse between app_non_user and app_user :)

Answer (score 3):

filters must be within an array, so `filters: ['app_non_users']`,